# Array to string conversion error from result returned by PDO

Tags: mysql, string, pdo

I'm getting errors because I converted from MySQL to PDO, after I changed to PDO, most of the line have solved, but one of them is related to string... I'm

getting error said

> Array to string conversion in **C:header.php** on line 573

the line I'm getting errors is

```
<?php if($msg_cnt>0) { echo '('.$msg_cnt.')'; }?></i></a>
```

please see code on last two lines... how can i solve that!

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['account_type'])){?><a href="#"><?php }?>


            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['account_type'])){ 

            $msg_cnt_q = $conn ->query("select * from messages where receiver_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' and receiver_read_status='unread'");
            $msg_cnt = $msg_cnt_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);?>


            <a href="http://www.xxxxxx/inbox.php">

            <i class="fa fa-bell fa-lg fa-color" style="padding-top:17px;">

            <?php if($msg_cnt>0) { echo '('.$msg_cnt.')'; }?></i></a>

            <?php }?>
```

thanks for your time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is a general PHP error when you try to print an array where you should have a single scalar value. Like concatenating the value with other strings.

The PDO function `fetch()` returns an array containing a row of data, not the count of rows in the result set.

PDO provides a different function `rowCount()` so you can know how many rows.

```
$row = $msg_cnt_q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$msg_cnt = $msg_cnt_q->rowCount();
```

Comment: `rowCount()` isn't guaranteed to work with `SELECT` queries. It would be better to use a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query.

Comment: @Barmar, `rowCount()` is not guaranteed to work across all PDO drivers, but it's implemented in the MySQL driver. Though if you set `MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` to false, you must first fetch all rows before `rowCount()` can return a correct value.